# Find value in sequence using XSL

Tags: xslt, sequence, xslt-2.0, functx

I want to check if a value exists in a sequence defined as

```
<xsl:variable name="some_seq" select="/root/word[@optional='no']/text()"/>
```

In the past, I've had success with Priscilla Walmsleys [function](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_is-value-in-sequence.html). For clarity, I reproduce it here as follows:

```
<xsl:function name="functx:is-value-in-sequence" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:anyAtomicType?"/>
    <xsl:param name="seq" as="xs:anyAtomicType*"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$value=$seq"/>
</xsl:function>
```

However, this time I need to make a case-insensitive comparison, and so I tried to wrap both `$value` and `$seq` with a `lower-case()`. Obviously, that didn't help much, as `$seq` is a sequence and `lower-case()` takes only strings.

Question: what is the best way to either 1) construct a sequence of lower-case strings, or 2) make a case-insensitive comparison analogous to `$value=$seq` above? TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: what is the best way to
>   either 1) construct a sequence of
>   lower-case strings

Not many people realize that you can use a function as the last location step in an XPATH 2.0 expression.

You can create a sequence of `lower-case()` string values with this expression:

```
/root/word[@optional='no']/text()/lower-case(.)
```

> or 2) make a case-insensitive
>   comparison analogous to $value=$seq
>   above?

Using that strategy, you can define a custom function that compares the `lower-case()` value of the `$value` and each string value in the `$seq`:

```
<xsl:function name="functx:is-value-in-sequence" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:anyAtomicType?"/>
    <xsl:param name="seq" as="xs:anyAtomicType*"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="some $word in $seq/lower-case(.) 
                               satisfies ($word = $value/lower-case(.))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Oh - I like that! Didn't know I could invoke the lower-case() function like that, although it makes a lot of sense. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use a "for-expression" inside the function to prepare a lower-case version of the sequence

```
<xsl:variable name="lcseq" select="for $i in $seq return lower-case($i)"/>
```

See Michael Kay's "XSLT 2.0 and XPATH 2.0, 4th ed", p. 640

(I haven't tested this)

Comment: thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay, man. I worked around this quite some time before your answer, and now that Mads' answer brought my attention back on the topic I'm gonna go for his solution as it was a little more specific. Thanks for the effort, though!